# array_filter меняет не только копию массива, но и оригинал

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив с заготовками под адреса ссылки, в которых плейсхолдером выступает символ `#`. Нужно для каждого `user` заменить плейсхолдер на имя этого пользователя. Решил делать через `array_filter`, скопировал массив, чтобы менять в цикле его копию. А у меня почему-то меняется и оригинал тоже (для простоты цикл не показываю).

```
$user     = 'user1';
$buttons  = array('user/#', 'user/#/delete', 'user/#/edit');
$copy     = $buttons;
$replaced = array_filter($copy, function(&$inner) use($user) {
    return $inner = str_replace('#', $user, $inner);
});
var_dump($buttons);
// array(3) { 
//      [0]=> string(10) "user/user1" 
//      [1]=> string(17) "user/user1/delete" 
//      [2]=> string(15) "user/user1/edit" 
// }
```

Comment: в принципе, решил через `$copy = array_values($buttons)` но всё равно не понял, почему так получается.

Comment: действительно, странный и вполне воспроизводимый результат :(

Comment: достаточно просто на array_map поменять.

Comment: Есть подозрение что баг закрался в `array_filter`. Если `$copy = &$buttons` то будет работать как ожидается.

Comment: Не надо функции не по назначению применять!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're doing it wrong](https://www.google.ru/search?q=you're%20doing%20it%20wrong&newwindow=1&biw=1242&bih=623&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI76SEobD2xwIVRJYsCh1u_QP8#imgrc=qcy7UbvZ7lNGFM%3A).

Вы неправильно используете язык. Функция `array_filter`, [согласно мануалу](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), фильтрует массив, т.е. в зависимости от возврата callback-метода добавляет фильтруемый элемент в выдачу.

Как справедливо заметили [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450608/array-filter-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB#comment480619_450608), для вашего случая (пройтись по массиву и обработать каждый элемент) должна использоваться функция [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php). То есть надо написать:

```
$replaced = array_map(function($inner) use($user) {
    return str_replace('#', $user, $inner);
}, $copy);
var_dump($buttons);
var_dump($replaced);
```

Выдача ниже:

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(6) "user/#"
>   [1]=>
>   string(13) "user/#/delete"
>   [2]=>
>   string(11) "user/#/edit"
> }
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(10) "user/user1"
>   [1]=>
>   string(17) "user/user1/delete"
>   [2]=>
>   string(15) "user/user1/edit"
> }
> ```

В вашем случае происходит следующее: вы пробегаетесь по всему массиву, меняете значение элемента (поэтому вам пришлось его сделать как `&$inner`, вместо `$inner`), и возвращаете результат оператора присваивания `$inner = replace(...)` (который в вашем случае всегда `true`). В результате у вас получается этакий извёрнутый `array_copy`.

Comment: согласен, переписал уже под `array_map`. но всё равно не понял, почему менялся исходный `$buttons`, если `$inner` у меня был-то уже от копии.

Comment: Потому что строка `$copy = $buttons;` не копирует массив, а создаёт ещё один указатель на существующий массив `$buttons`. Это происходит неявно. Для явного копирования элементов требуется воспользоваться функцией `array_copy()`. А почему `$copy` менялся — понятно?

Comment: с `$copy` как раз всё понятно. а вот с указателем - нет. почему тогда `$copy[0] = FALSE;` изменит нулевой индекс только у `$copy`? и еще цитата: "Обратите внимание, что при присваивании массива всегда происходит копирование значения. Чтобы скопировать массив по ссылке, вам нужно использовать оператор ссылки." http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Comment: Прошу прощения, давно не ел php, ошибся с массивом. Да, действительно, `$copy = $button` копирует массив, но содержатся же в нём ссылки :-) К сожалению, пруфы с ходу найти не удаётся, или я не могу нормально задать вопрос гуглу. Судя по всему, происходит «мелкое» (shallow) копирование объекта (массива), только на 1 уровень. Если вы знакомы с C++, то сейчас происходит что-то в духе: `int **t = new int*[n]; for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) t[i] = s[i];`. При этом данные внутри указателей не копируются. На самом деле чуть сложнее, т.к. вмешиваются всякие счётчики ссылок и т.п.